# fputcsv setting semicolon delimiter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, stored-procedures, delimiter

I am able to grab the data returned from a stored procedure and set it to an array.

After that, I am opening a file path to upload a file.

The file was spitting out a text file with a comma delimiter.

I found that you can use fputcsv to set the delimiter to a semicolon.

Here is my attempt, starting with the SP call:

```
<?php
  $filename = 'myFile';

  $thecall = mysqli_query($dbc, "CALL SP_SVC($servicecodes)");

  if($thecall){
    $out = array(); 

    while($row = $thecall->fetch_assoc()){
      $out[] = $row;
    }

    $file = fopen("//folderName/IS/business/reports/TXT Report files/$filename.txt", 'w');
    foreach($out as $fields){
      fputcsv($file, explode(';',$fields), ";");
    }
  }
?>
```

Using the above, I am getting an error in the console that reads:

```
Warning:  explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in 
D:\htdocs\mySite\api\serviceReport.php on line 99

Warning:  fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in 
D:\htdocs\mySite\api\serviceReport.php on line 99
```

Line 99 is where the fputcsv function is located.

In the foreach loop, I tried to echo out the $fields variable, and I get the following error:

```
Notice:  Array to string conversion in D:\htdocs\mySite\api\serviceReport.php on line 99
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I set the delimiter to a semicolon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
fputcsv($file, explode(';',$fields), ";");
```

`$fields` is a row of the data from the database, so instead of using `explode`, you should just write it straight out...

```
fputcsv($file, $fields, ";");
```

But as you read the file in and store it, then write it, you could combine these two steps into one to save the interim array...

```
$filename = 'myFile';

$thecall = mysqli_query($dbc, "CALL SP_SVC($servicecodes)");

if($thecall){
    $file = fopen("//folderName/IS/business/reports/TXT Report files/$filename.txt", 'w');
    while($row = $thecall->fetch_assoc()){
        fputcsv($file, $row, ";");
    }
    fclose($file);
}
```

Comment: I think you have solved my problem.  I'm still testing, but the file is now being spit out with semicolon delimiters.  Thank you, sir.